# Microsoft Graph - Filtering with umlaut and other unicode characters

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How can I formulate a Microsoft Graph `/myOrganization/users` OData query that contains non-English characters such as Germanic Umlauts?

Example:
I have a user in my tenant with the name 'Thomas Müller'. If I query

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myOrganization/users?$filter=startswith(surname,'mu')`

I get

```
"value": [
    {
      "displayName": "Thomas Müller",
      "givenName": "Thomas ",
      "surname": "Müller"
    }
]
// Result truncated for brevity
```

but if I search for

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myOrganization/users?$filter=startswith(surname,'mü')`

I get

`"value": []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph seems to support international characters now as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can try encoding the string to utf8 format.